# Is there a way to install .net framework 4.5.2 or higher on Mac OS X?

Tags: .net, macos, mono, xamarin-studio, .net-4.5.2

I want to compile c# project with .net 4.5.2 framework in Xamarin Studio. When I open project and look for Target Framework, there is .NET Framework 4.5.2 (not installed). So it doesn't compile. Is there a way to install .net framework 4.5.2 or higher on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Target `Mono / .Net 4.5` for right now for cross platform development.

The Mono team is integrating Microsoft's reference source and Mono is being currently built using one profile, `net_4_x`, with contract assemblies for the other profiles.

[Mono 4.2.0 Alpha](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.2.0/):

> While Microsoft is working towards .NET Core: a redistributable and
>   re-imagined version of .NET, the project remains a work in progress.
>   Mono at this point continues to provide an API that tracks the .NET
>   desktop/server version.
>
> This means that most of the code that we have integrated comes from
>   the ReferenceSource drop. In the future, we will deliver a “Mono Core”
>   along the same lines of .NET Core to allow the use of the Mono runtime
>   with the new library distribution system that is being developed with
>   CoreFX.
>
> In this release, we have either ported components that were either
>   incomplete or buggy in Mono and were relatively easy to port to Mono.
>   There is much more to be done in this area. If you are interested in
>   tracking those efforts, check the project status.
>
> Mono ships now with a subset of the referencesource that have been
>   adjusted to work with Mono’s class libraries or have been updated to
>   be cross platform.

Comment: What's `xplat`? External platform?

Comment: @isomorphismes xplat = cross-platform, i.e. linux, windows, osx, etc.

Comment: xplat = fork the Windows version and have failing tests / builds.

Answer (score 2):

If you just mean *to build against* (not to actually run), then the reference assemblies now ship on nuget, so simply add a package reference:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies"
    Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
```

You can now *build* against netfx on mac. This is mostly useful when multi-targeting against something that targets netfx and .NET Core, and you're mostly *running* against .NET Core during development.